# Using brute force to determine original input data from a hash value

Tags: hash, blockchain, brute-force, cryptocurrency

[What is Hashing - from blockgeeks.com](https://blockgeeks.com/guides/what-is-hashing/)

I came across this article explaining that to determine the original input from a 128-bit hash value, using brute force, the worst case scenario would be 2^128 – 1 attempts (meaning there are 2^128 possible answers - from what I understand).

But... Isn't 128 bits the length of the hash - not the length of the original input? Wouldn't you have to try all possible cases of input data? And wouldn't that be a totally different number of possibilities unless the input data were also exactly 128 1s or 0s?

Comment: You are correct. The article is a little sloppy in that spot. The mathematics is tad bit more complicated, and in truth there is no guarantee that you can ever recover the actual input A from H(A) because there may be two (or more!) values A1 and A2 such that H(A1) = H(A2). However, for most applications of hash functions, *any* input that hashes to the same value is good enough to break the system. And for blockchain applications, the input may very well be 128 bits (or 256 bits for SHA256).